# Why does my power chord sound higher when I play the same notes on a different string on my electric guitar?

Tags: guitar, chords, electric-guitar

For example I play the B power chord by pressing the 2nd fret on the A string, 4th fret on the D string and the 4th fret on G the string. It sounds higher than when I play the power chord by pressing 7th fret on E string, 9th fret on A string, and 9th fret on D string. My guitar is in tune by the way, and it should be the same notes right which are B F# and B right all of the same octave right? If I play them individually they sound the same but they sound a little different when I play them in a chord.

Comment: I'm guessing you really mean 'brighter' ie more trebly, rather than 'higher'.

Comment: Is it electric or acoustic guitar, and if it's electric, which pickup you are using?

Answer (score 6):

Most answers have addressed the pitch vs timbre issue. It might not actually sound "higher" just brighter.

I'll play devil's advocate and say that maybe it *does* sound higher. You say both notes are in tune, have you checked both with a tuner? In my experience most budget guitars have imperfect intonation, and it really shows higher on the neck. The B on the 6th string might be higher than the B on the 5th string even if both *strings* are in tune.

If you have thoroughly checked the intonation of the B/F# in various positions then I'd say this is just an example of how timbre changes across the fretboard

EDIT: It appears I misread the question and you say that the lower position sounds higher, not the "higher" position. It could still be an intonation thing due to action, nut height, technique. But I think it's safe to say that the aural phenomenon you're hearing is one of timbre, not pitch.

Comment: A nut that is higher than it should be can cause the lower frets to play slightly sharp due to the extra bending of the strings to reach the fret.

Answer (score 4):

Here's why;

The B power chord played in the first instance has its root just two inches from the nut. It will, therefore, have a tighter, crisper timbre than the B power chord played in the second position (which is just about 12 inches from both the nut and the bridge).

Just for perspective, pluck the open A, D, and G strings in three different places:

1. Right up next to the nut
2. In the middle of the fingerboard
3. Right down next to the bridge

Hear the difference in timbre?

That's the wonderful thing about playing guitar.
You can achieve different sounds by playing, phrasing chords, and strumming at different places over the length of the strings.

Try strumming the B chord at the beginning of George Michael's song Faith, in the first example position above and then the second.
See how the second one sounds better, and more like the original record?

Magic stuff!

Comment: You're commenting on *where* the strings are *strummed* There's no mention of that in the question. Although what you say is true, it doesn't answer the question. I dare say OP is strumming all at the same place near the bridge!

Comment: I addressed the location of the chord phrasing at the beginning and end of my answer, Tim.  The plucking strings bit in the middle was purely to compare/contrast the food-for-thought of 'end of string brightness' versus 'middle of string warmth'.

Comment: The end of the answer doesn't really explain anything beyond "Magic stuff"

Comment: If playing, teaching, and performing live music isn't "magic stuff" to us, then we are in the wrong business.

Answer (score 1):

It's more due to the gauge of the strings. The 'lower' sounding power chord played on the bottom 3 strings will sound 'beefier' due to the heavier strings feeding more signal to the pups, while the 'higher' sounding one, using strings 5, 4 and 3 will feed less signal, being thinner.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hearing a higher pitch when you play the same notes higher on the fret, you could have a problem with your intonation.  That can be fixed by adjusting the height of your bridge in some cases, or changing your strings in other cases.

It's also possible that the pitch is the same (e.g. if it still sounds right musically) and you are simply hearing different harmonics in the strings. This is normal and can be used for artistic effect.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different explanation: I suppose you have power chords with some distortion (an acoustic guitar also does have some non-linearity, but to a less extent). Distortion changes the waveform and thus the harmonic spectrum. If we distort a signal composed of a root (1) and a fifth (3/2) this results in getting the octave below the root (1/2) into the harmonic spectrum. So a powerchord will sound one octave under the actual root. But the amount of this effect depends on some things, like the intonation of the fifth, or the balance of the notes. These things might change over the fretboard (as we go up the intonation tends to get worse, also the balance might shift), which could result in a change of this powerchord effect.

What you need to remember is that with non-linearities distorting the sum of two signals will not be the same as summing the single distorted signals.